# I can't get his implementation of Merge Sort right. Debug it

Tags: c++, mergesort

Here i'm trying to implement Merge sort using auxiliary array, similar to the implementation by Bob Sedgewick, of Algorithms class, Princeton(Coursera).
But I can't get this right. It doesn't sort the array. Where's the bug?

```
#include <iostream>
void MergeArr(int *first_arr,int lo, int mid, int hi){
    int i, j, k;
    int *aux_arr = new int[hi - lo + 1];
    for(i = lo;i <= hi;i++){
        aux_arr[i] = first_arr[i];
    }
    i = lo, j = mid + 1;
    for(k = lo;k <= hi;k++){
        if(i > mid){
            first_arr[k] = aux_arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if(j > hi){
            first_arr[k] = aux_arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if(aux_arr[i] < aux_arr[j]){
            first_arr[k] = aux_arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            first_arr[k] = aux_arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    delete(aux_arr);
}
void SortArr(int *main_arr, int lo_place, int hi_place){
    if(lo_place >= hi_place)
        return;
    int mid = lo_place + (hi_place - lo_place)/2;
    SortArr(main_arr, lo_place, mid);
    SortArr(main_arr, mid + 1, hi_place);
    MergeArr(main_arr,lo_place, mid, hi_place);
}
void display(int *show_arr, int show_size){
    cout<<"\nThe array: ";
    for(int i = 0;i < show_size;i++)
        cout<<show_arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
}
int main(){
int len_arr;
cout<<"\nEnter the size: ";
cin>>len_arr;
int *arr = new int[len_arr];
cout<<"\nEnter the elements: ";
for(int i = 0;i < len_arr;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
display(arr, len_arr);
SortArr(arr, 0, len_arr - 1);
cout<<"\nAfter sorting the array: ";
display(arr, len_arr);
```

}

Here's the output: 
Enter the size: 4
Enter the element: 4 3 2 1
The array: 4 3 2 1
After sorting the array:
The array: 1 3 1 1

Will appreciate any help. R.

Comment: Your initial temp copy indexing in your merge algorithm is wrong. Look at the indexing you're using : `aux_arr[i]`, and note particularly the *size* beforehand. Consider what that `i` indexing is actually doing, where it is starting, where it finishes, etc. I stopped reading there. Good luck.

Comment: "Debug it" - no, dude, we aren't walking and talking debuggers. Please, learn how to use a _software_ debugger (gdb, lldb, maybe others) first, _try to actually use it to solve the problem_, and only then ask a question here.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. That was helpful man.

Answer (score 1):

I got it guys :-)
While copying main array into auxiliary array in the Merge function, there was bug in the index.

```
int size = hi - lo + 1;
    int *aux_arr = new int[size];
    for(i = 0, j = lo;i <= size;i++){
        aux_arr[i] = first_arr[j++];
    }
```

Here's the code with correction.
Also as the auxiliary array index starts from 0 to the size, I'll have to change the index in the final merging loop

```
i = 0, j = mid - lo + 1;
    for(k = lo;k <= hi;k++){
        if(i > mid - lo) first_arr[k] = aux_arr[j++];
        else if(j > hi - lo) first_arr[k] = aux_arr[i++];
        else if(aux_arr[i] < aux_arr[j]) first_arr[k] = aux_arr[i++];
        else first_arr[k] = aux_arr[j++];
    }
```

Rest will remain same.
Thanks for commenting, it really helped. :-)